# Using Foxx CLI to Create Service

Tags: arangodb, pyarango, arangodb-foxx

I am using Foxx service CLI Server to create API service during time error came as"
Server refused authorization. Either your credentials are invalid or the user has insufficient privileges" so kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

You can add to every command `-u <user> -p <file_with_password>`

Github [issue](https://github.com/arangodb/foxx-cli/issues/44) as reference